# Macbook pro 2019 connect to 3 displays

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, macbook

I have a new MacBook Pro 13 with 4 Thunderbolt and I am unable to connect it to 3 monitors.

Docking Station: [Elgato](https://www.elgato.com/en/dock/thunderbolt-3):

a. Connected with Display Port to [P2414hb](https://www.dell.com/lv/business/p/dell-p2414h/pd)

b. Connected with [Kanex USB-C to Display Port Adapter](https://www.kanex.com/usb-c-dp-adapter) with P2414hb

The Elgato is connected to the left side of Thunderbolt.

MacBook:

c. Directly Connected [Kanex USB-C to HDMI adapter](https://www.kanex.com/usb-c-hdmi-4k-adapter) with [PH2419H](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07F8XZN69)

The MacBook screen is closed, I am only able to detect two screens at a time.
depends on the order of connection (docking station or adapter first).

Is it even feasible?

Comment: I don't know specifics, but you usually need to get rid of any docking stations to do this & use 'one plug per screen'.

Comment: If I connect only the docking, where there are two screens connected to the docking I can see both of them.

Comment: @Tetsujin tried to connect 3 adapters (2 DP, 1 HDMI) directly (in different ways) to the MacBook, still only recognises two.

Comment: Is this the one? https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.8-quad-core-13-mid-2019-touch-bar-specs.html

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes it is

Comment: Then it can only do 2 external displays.

Comment: Thanks! There is any 13" that can do 3 displays?

Comment: The entire range is listed on that site.